# Как получить все возможные вариации spintax-текста

Tags: c#

Есть spintax-строка.

```
{{Hello|Howdy|Hola}|{Hello|Howdy|Hola}}
```

Интересует вопрос как найти все возможные комбинации?

Нашел код в сети, однако он находит только случайную вариацию

```
public  String SpinRE(String text)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Match m = reg.Match(text);
        if (!m.Success) break;
        parts = m.Value.Substring(1, m.Value.Length - 2).Split('|');
        text = text.Substring(0, m.Index) + parts[rand.Next(parts.Length)] + text.Substring(m.Index + m.Length);
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Вам нужен метод, возвращающий массив всех возможных комбинаций входного текста? т.е. для {{Hello|Howdy|Hola}|{Hello|Howdy|Hola}} это: "Hello Hello", "Hello Howdy","Hello Hola", "Howdy Hello"  и т.д. Приведите пример (хотя бы частичный) вывода который хотите получить в результате выполнения требуемого метода